# need a little assistance with positioning of my <li>Home</li> line of code on my page

Tags: html, css

i have been following a tutorial perfectly, but for some reason, my code isnt producing what is displayed on the video. i have this html document im working on, http://jsbin.com/pizaje/1/edit?html,output

and my

Home

is in the wrong place, as shown in these images. mine has the word "Home" above the "BBC UK" news header

but it really has to have the word "Home" underneath the "BBC UK" and i don't know what i have done or what to do to fix?

is there any assistance anyone is able to give me ?

Answer (score 2):

Your break in code is a `class` but the style in css is an `id`

change the css to the `class` like following

```
.break {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: that fixed it thank you,but isnt an "id" int he CSS world a "." and "class" is a "#"???

Comment: nope.... follow to w3c...  class is `.` and id is `#`
Please learn more about CSS Selector
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: It's the reverse. `#` = ID , `.` = class.

Comment: wow, how could i be so stupid for something so simple, i do apologize! and i thank you guys for your help! the problem is fixed and i shall remember this vital information from here on out!

Comment: Glad to see that my answer help you :)
A check on accept answer will help other people to see the correct answer and it's really help me ^^.